# Можно ли разделить различные окна pygame на отдельные файлы .py?

Tags: python, pygame

Как разделить разные окна на отдельные файлы, так как в одном файле со временем все начинает путаться?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо заведомо писать код в разных модулях, а затем по необходимости импортировать их к нужному модулю.
Чтобы сделать это, тебе нужно сегментировать твою программу на процессы (*устно или письменно, как в примере*), которые в дальнейшем и будут разными модулями.

**Например:** Есть dashboard с показателями с каких-то датчиков - это один модуль (главный).
Есть программа снимающая, обрабатывающая и передающая показатели с датчиков в dashboard - это второй модуль.
Есть программа которая выполняет соединение и запись полученных данных на сервере - это уже третий модуль.

И важную роль разбиение на модули, играет снижение нагрузки на ОЗУ.